# How to implement Android JobScheduler/JobService?

Tags: android, job-scheduling

Starting Android N, google is getting all strict about how often a background task can execute. To experiment with this I have written a small implementation https://github.com/snijsure/JobScheduler

- While researching it I have found several references on stack-overflow that indicate one can not have repeating Job that can run with frequency less than 15 minutes. I have yet to find concrete reference to that any Google documentation or Google authored examples. If anyone has found that reference would appreciate a pointer.
- I want my job to run my job at say 15 minute interval, with some leniency that Android might deem appropriate

  `builder.setMinimumLatency(REFRESH_INTERVAL_N)
  builder.setBackoffCriteria(5000, BACKOFF_POLICY_LINEAR)
  builder.setOverrideDeadline(REFRESH_INTERVAL_N)`

Are above parameter appropriate to achive this.

- While running on version 27 I have discovered that merely calling

`jobFinished(params,true)`

doesn't reschedule job to be run in next 15 min, but one has to explicitly call `jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo)`, is `jobFinished(params,true)` broken, or my use of it the example is broken?

- Lastly, is there way to debug JobScheduling decisions that android is making, and is there way to reduce this magical limit of 15 minutes, at least with `debug` builds?

Comment: "I have found several references on stack-overflow that indicate one can not have repeating Job that can run with frequency less than 15 minutes. I have yet to find concrete reference to that.." - `JobInfo.getMinPeriodMillis()` <-- 15 minutes

Comment: Thanks Mark, indeed `JobInfo.getMinPeriodMillis()` on device running 27, returns 900000. That is very strange way by google to document that limit!